# '.' is not recognized as a internal command (React Package.Json)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, package.json

I cannot deploy my react project on github pages because the change that I did in my package json shows the error below:

I just added inside of Scripts: publicar

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "publicar": "npm run build && ./node_modules/bin/gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

I'm using '.' because i need to access the node_modules that is located in a different place that my package json.

When I execute the command 'npm run publicar' shows me this error:

'.' is not recognized as a internal command

When I execute the 'npm run publicar' should not show me errors and should show 'published'

Comment: stdunbar yes I tried but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`npm` runs with `node_modules/bin` in its `PATH`. You should just be able to use `gh-pages` the same way you use `react-scripts`.

I would also advise using a [*pre-script*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) instead of chaining commands

```js
"prepublicar": "npm run build",
"publicar": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Comment: Hi Phill thanks to collaborate, did worked now, but now i'm with another issue. Should show my app, but is showing one thing like a step by step about react.
https://igorgalliardo.github.io/my-first-app-react/

Comment: @IgorGalliardo sorry, can't help you with that without seeing code. You should probably ask a new question if this particular one is solved

Comment: That's fine thank you :)